# AttributeError: type object 'WebTablePage' has no attribute 'load' in selenium using pytest

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pytest, attributeerror

I am learning selenium in python with pytest, I am facing this below error. I have searched this error all over the internet and tried all the possible advice, but nothing is working.
I am just trying to load the website, it is opening the browser but failing with this error. I don't know what i am missing, Any lead would be helpful.

> FAILED Tests/test_webtable.py::test_webtablepage - AttributeError: type object 'WebTablePage' has no attribute 'load'

**Code**

Page Object Class(webtablepage.py) under pages folder.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

class WebTablePage:

#URL
 URL = 'https://demoqa.com/webtables'

#Intializers
 def __init__(self,browser):
     browser = self.browser

 def load(self,browser):
     self.browser.get(self.URL)
```

Pytest fixture(conftest.py) under Tests folder.

```
import pytest
import selenium.webdriver

@pytest.fixture
def browser():
   #initialize the chrome instance
 driver = selenium.webdriver.Chrome()
   
   #Making the Driver wait for 10 seconds to load elements
 driver.implicitly_wait(10)

   #Return the webdriver instances for the setup
 yield driver

   #Quit the webdriver instances for the cleanup
 driver.quit()
```

Test function (test_webtable.py) under Tests folder

```
from Pages.webtablepage import WebTablePage

def test_webtablepage(browser):
   Webtable_page =  WebTablePage

  # Given the demoa qa Webtables page
   Webtable_page.load()
```

Comment: You are using a class instead of an instance, you probaly want `Webtable_page = WebTablePage()` instead.

Comment: Hi @MrBeanBremen thanks for helping, I have tried this one too, Still throwing the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `WebTablePage` constructor is called incorrectly. It must be called with the `browser` argument.

Change this:

```py
def test_webtablepage(browser):
   Webtable_page =  WebTablePage
```

To this:

```py
def test_webtablepage(browser):
   Webtable_page =  WebTablePage(browser)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Change the**

```
Webtable_page = WebTablePage
```

**to**

```
Webtable_page = WebTablePage()
```